# How to ignore dependency if already installed by Poetry install

Tags: python, containers, python-poetry

I want to install `package-1` using `poetry install`, `package-1` depends on `package-2`, so when executing `poetry install` - poetry tries to update `package-2`.
But `package-2` have no published compiled release, so it should be compiled - which can't be done as I am running on very thin container so I don't have even GCC.

I have the precompiled `package-2` and I install that before the `poetry lock` - so the dependency is met, but `poetry install` still tries to compile the `package-2`.

Is there a way to force poetry to ignore packages that are already installed globally in the system? or at least not fail on exception when trying to compile a package?